# why is this javascript regex not match second and fourth pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

the new_data output is `",$,2,$,4,$,"`

but I am expecting `",$,$,$,$,$,"`, can someone kindly explain why to me? Thanks.

```js
var data = ",1,2,3,4,5,";
var pattern = /,\d,/g
var new_data = data.replace(pattern, function(match){
  return ",$,";
});
console.log(new_data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `,\d,` eats up `,1,` . Then the regex engine tries to match the next `,\d,`, since the first pattern eats up the `,` which exists before `2` , `,2,` wouldn't be visible to the regex engine. Likewise the same happens for `4`.

So you could use positive lookahead.

```
string.replace(/,\d(?=,)/g, ",$")
```

Here the second comma won't be matched since lookarounds are assertions which won't capture any single character.

Comment: if I use ?: even if it doesn't capture the ",", it still eat up ",", seem only ?= lookahead not eating up any character, nice to know something new about regex, thanks @avinash-raj

Comment: yes `(?:)`  (_non-capturing group_) should match the character .

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by removing the last comma

```
/,\d/g
```

The problem is that the second comma is being consumed by the first match.

Example:

```
,1,2,3,4,5
```

Match 1: `,1,`
`,2,` is not a match because the first comma is consumed by Match 1

Mathc 2: `,3,`
`,4,` is not a match because the first comma is consumed by Match 2

Comment: but this would slihtly modify the meaning of the pattern. It would match, if it ends wiht `,5`, not only if it ends with `,5,`

Comment: Yes you are right, but I am going to keep my answer because the OP might find this useful. Thank you for your comment @dognose